# SQL Query with LISTAGG and CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, listagg

Can anyone help me here to solve the below Problem,

I wanted to use `CASE` with `LISTAGG` at same time.

using sql I am doing

```
LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) AS SERVICES
```

So the Output is working as good only

```
**SERVICES**
Row 1 : 50|100|128
Row 2 : 100|100|128
```

so here I wanted to write a case or if else logic (if 50|100|128) it should reflect as Yes else if 100|100|128 then it should reflect as No

can you please help me with this.

Comment: use of `listagg` suggests this is for oracle. i removed the mysql tag and added oracle.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `case` in the `listagg()`:

```
LISTAGG(CASE WHEN G.IGROUP_ID IN (50, 100, 128) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END ,'|')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) AS SERVICES
```

This assumes that everything that is not `YES` is `NO`.  If this is not true, then just add another `WHEN` clause.

EDIT:

A literal interpretation of the question would suggest:

```
(CASE LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID , '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) 
      WHEN '50|100|128' THEN 'Yes'
      WHEN '100|100|128' THEN 'No'
 END) AS SERVICES
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon , It works like Charm, Just want to get some knowledge, Is there anyway I can use Like within Case , For Ex Like '50|100%' THEN as YES and '100|100%' THEN NO. I wanted to produce this way

Comment: END) close bracket should not be present after END in first SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) = '50|100|128' THEN 'YES'
WHEN LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) = '100|100|128' THEN 'NO' END AS COL_NAME
```

or you can keep `LISTAGG(G.IGROUP_ID,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY G.igroup_id) AS SERVICES` inside a subquery and apply `case` in the outer query